# How to deserialize xml in which a node contains html tags?

Tags: c#, html, xml, .net-3.5, xml-serialization

```
<Translation> (  benzene  OR  pyrobenzole  OR  pyrobenzol  OR  &quot;phenyl      hydride&quot;              OR  phene  OR  &quot;fenzen  czech  &quot;  cyclohexatriene  &quot;coal  naphtha&quot;  OR  &quot;benzolo  italian  &quot;  benzole  benzol  &quot;benzen  polish  &quot;  &quot;benzeen  dutch  &quot;  ) The chemical name <b>benzene</b> was identified.<br>The following terms were added from ChemIDplus:<br><b>pyrobenzole</b><br><b>pyrobenzol</b><br><b>phenyl hydride</b><br><b>phene</b><br><b>fenzen  czech </b><br><b>cyclohexatriene</b><br><b>coal naphtha</b><br><b>benzolo  italian </b><br><b>benzole</b><br><b>benzol</b><br><b>benzen  polish </b><br><b>benzeen  dutch </b><br>CAS Registry Number: <b>71-43-2</b><br></Translation>
```

I get the string from a web service and it doesnt send the html in cdata section. 
The error that I get is:
System.Xml.XmlException: The 'br' start tag on line 1 does not match the end tag

I am using .net 3.5, webclient to consume a REST web service.

Comment: You should post actual xml, because your example has an ending br tag.

Comment: Embedding unencoded HTML in an XML document sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: Modify the web service to encode the html in a cdata section.

Comment: Edited to add the actual XML. I can't change the web service as its external. Is there any way to parse the XML and extract the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem. I could solve it by including the namespace for HTML.

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

This error will be thrown for all empty elements like `<br />`, `<hr />`, `<input />` and so on.